# StringBuilder, differences between two syntaxes

Tags: c#, performance, stringbuilder

Is there a difference between :

```
StringBuilder requete = new StringBuilder();
requete.Append(" INSERT into " + listeLibelleTable[index] + " ( ");
```

and

```
StringBuilder requete = new StringBuilder();
requete.Append(" INSERT into ");
requete.Append(listeLibelleTable[index]);
requete.Append(" ( ");
```

When I say "difference" I mean in terms of performance, if this code is in a loop for example.

I think these line

```
requete.Append(" INSERT into " + listeLibelleTable[index] + " ( ");
```

is resolved at compile time so It should not be any impact in terms of performance but I'm not sure of that

Comment: Your string is so small, it is overkill to use a `StringBuilder` with your example code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unless `listeLibelleTable[index]` can indeed be resolved at compile time (which I greatly doubt), using the string concatenation seems to be counter productive to the use of the `StringBuilder`.

In your second example you are concatenating a string and then appending it instead of appending to the `StringBuilder`.

In either case, you should probably use [`AppendFormat`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder.appendformat.aspx) for readability:

```
requete.AppendFormat(" INSERT into {0} ( ", listeLibelleTable[index]);
```

Comment: do you mean AppendFormat?  I don't see FormatAppend as a StringBuilder method.

Answer (score 1):

Your first code is performing the concatenation, building a complete string and *then* appending it to the `StringBuilder`. Assuming you're also going to append other things, the second form could be a little bit faster... it doesn't need the temporary string with the result of that part of the concatenation.

On the other hand, if you're performing a database operation, the difference is going to be immeasurably small.

Answer (score 0):

I think doing this:

```
" INSERT into " + listeLibelleTable[index] + " ( "
```

you use more memory to store result of concat operation!

Answer (score 0):

String concatenation will create new String object and copy exisiting value, and despose old string. show it will be slow.
check http://kaioa.com/node/59 for reference